# Find a circle cylinder parallel to the z-axis with given volume

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Find a $3\pi$ volume circle cylinder parallel to the z-axis such that :

$\iiint_{V} x \, dx  dy  dz = 4 \pi$

$\iiint_{V} y \, dx  dy  dz = -5 \pi$

$\iiint_{V} z \, dx  dy  dz = -5 \pi$

Any idea how to approach this problem ?

I tried using cylindrical coordinates $x=rcos\theta,y=rsin\theta,z=z$,the problems is that $\iiint_{V} x \, dx  dy  dz=\iiint_{V} r^2cos\theta \, dr  d\theta  dz=0$.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: $3\pi$ or $3d$?

Comment: it's $3\pi$....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(x_0,y_0)$ be the coordinates of the axis of the cylinder, $R$ its radius, and $a<b$ the coordinates of its bottom and top disk. The 4 constraints are:
$$\pi R^2(b-a)=3\pi,
$$
$$3\pi x_0=4\pi,
$$
$$3\pi y_0=-5\pi,
$$
$$\pi R^2\frac{b^2-a^2}2=-5\pi.
$$
i.e.
$$x_0=\frac43,\;y_0=-\frac53,\;
$$
$$R^2(b-a)=3,\;b+a=-\frac{10}3.
$$

Comment: $\iiint_{V} z \, dx  dy  dz = -5 \pi=\iint_{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2\le R^2}dxdy\int_a^bzdz=\pi R^2\frac{b^2-a^2}2,$ not $\pi R^2(b-a).$

Comment: $0\leq z\leq -\frac{10}3$ makes no sense. The correct answers are $(x-\frac{4}{3})^2 + (y+\frac{5}{3})\le\frac3h,-\frac53-\frac h2\le z\le-\frac53+\frac h2,$ for any $h>0.$